# how to get the count of specific letters occurances from a array of words

Tags: php, arrays, string, count

i want to get the count of some text that starts with specific letter with "/" 
 just like as follows. i want the count of all "A/" occurancves in that array.

```
<?php
$arr_vals = array("A/V","A/B","B/A","D/D","A/v","A/A");


$count_A = count($arr_vals,"A/*");


?>
```

Comment: You’ll want to use regular expressions to match the pattern you want. Alternatively, you can use `explode()` using the slash as the split delimiter and check the resulting array.

Comment: @JohnEllmore no need of explode.. see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and easy one..Here is your solution:-

```
$input = preg_quote('A/', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$arr_vals = array("A/V","A/B","B/A","D/D","A/v","A/A");
$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $arr_vals);
echo count($result); die;
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) can be used to take your entire array and compute a result, through the use of a callback function.  We can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to define what your pattern is.  Combining these two things, we have your solution:

```
$arr_vals = array("A/V","A/B","B/A","D/D","A/v","A/A");


function match($carry, $item)  {
  return $carry + preg_match('/A\/./', $item);
}

var_dump(array_reduce($arr_vals, 'match', 0));  // Returns 4
```

Comment: @nfnneil No, no it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry I was debating that immediately afterward, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch) would also work and uses shell wildcards, e.g. `*` and `?`:

```
function count_pattern(array $input, string $pattern): int {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($input as $string) {
        $count += fnmatch($pattern, $string);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

**Usage**

```
$arr_vals = array("A/V","A/B","B/A","D/D","A/v","A/A");
echo count_pattern($arr_vals, "A/*"); // 4
```

<sup>Note: in order to use scalar type hints and returns you need PHP7. If you are not on PHP7 yet, you can just omit them.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes the correct answer is

```
$input = preg_quote('A/', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$arr_vals = array("A/V","A/B","B/A","D/D","A/v","A/A");
$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $arr_vals);
echo count($result); die;
```